# Words before and after selected text

Tags: shell, sed, awk

My SQL query looks like this...

> sekect * FROM mail_headers a LEFT JOIN
>   mail_headers_body b ON a.mailid=b.id
>   blah blah blah

I can select the lines before and after the result, using -A, -B switches. But how do I find the 4 words before and after the selected text?

```
grep -i 'JOIN mail_headers_body' mysql-gen.log
```

This will return the query mentioned above. But what I want to know is 4 "words" before the selected text. i.e.

```
FROM mail_headers a LEFT
```

And 4 (or 5) words after...

```
b ON a.mailid=b.id blah
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
grep -Eio '( *[^ ]* *){4}JOIN mail_headers_body( *[^ ]* *){4}'
```

It should give you this output:

```
 FROM mail_headers a LEFT JOIN mail_headers_body b ON a.mailid=b.id blah
```

Comment: I removed the -i switch because my table names are case sensitive. I tried to added the -w switch because I want to select only the specific word. # why does the table mail_headers_body_sent appear? I am looking for only the table mentioned above.

Comment: added the word boundary like # \<mail_headers_body\>

Answer (score 0):

you can use awk,

```
$ echo $sql|awk -F"JOIN mail_headers_body" '{ 
    m=split($1,a," ");n=split($2,b," ")
    print a[m-3],a[m-2],a[m-1],a[m]; print b[1],b[2],b[3],b[4] }'
```

this is assuming you have only 1 "JOIN mail_headers_body". Otherwise, use a for loop to iterate the fields.

Comment: # If I change it to following, it prints $mytable as is, and not the actual table name.

# cat mysql-gen.log | awk -vRS="$mytable"  'NR==1{for(i=NF-3;i<=NF;i++) print "$mytable " $i}'

# I am trying to use this statement in a shell script.

Comment: because you are not passing the shell variable to awk correctly. use -v. `awk -vRS="$mytable" -v mytable="$mytable" '{.... print mytable" "$i}'`

Comment: Does it return all the instances? in my case, it is returning only the first line it finds.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the AWK, GREP, and CAT combinations in a one-liner:

```
cat YOURFILE | grep -i 'JOIN mail_headers_body' | awk '{ for(i;i<=NF;i++){ if($i ~ /JOIN/) { a = i } } for(x=4;x!=0;x--){ before=before" "$(a-x)} a+=3; for(x=0;x<4;x++) { after=after" "$(a+x) } print "BEFORE: "before" \nAFTER: "after  }'
```

update: I just removed a--;  from the awk. I just realized it was skipping the first word before JOIN which is LEFT.

Comment: More than 4 words are returned in before and after

Comment: Based on the query you show in your post, I get the following back: 

BEFORE:  * FROM mail_headers a 

AFTER:  b ON a.mailid=b.id blah

That is 4 words. A word is defined as a group of characters with a space on both sides. So a.mailid=b.id is one word.

Comment: After update (removing the a--;) it now returns the following. BEFORE:  FROM mail_headers a LEFT 
AFTER:  ON a.mailid=b.id blah blah

Comment: UUOC, and `grep -i` is equivalent to `IGNORECASE=1` in awk. Essentially, just 1 awk command will do.

Comment: However, the requirement is to search for 'JOIN mail_headers_body'. I do that only in the grep. The awk statement is taking the line and searching for the field number for the word JOIN and basing all field references in both directions from there. So it won't in my particular case.